# How to make a photo zoom, setting aspect ratio and then zooming leaves white area in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, scrollview, aspect-ratio

[[After scrolling : Problem White Screen][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr9kE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr9kE.png)

[After Zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duSej.png)

[[Before Zoom image setted aspect ratio]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RmoS.png)

I am implementing a photo view page, which includes just a photo. Functionalities : Zoom.

As the image is of size 1024x510. I have implemented aspect ratio and set the imageview frame to the screensize. I have implemented using Scrollview and imageview concept.

The problem is that, when I zoom the image white screen is also zoomed. Problem is the white space os imageview while zooming.
.
Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()



print(imageIndex)
self.scrollV.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
self.scrollV.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
 self.scrollV.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
self.scrollV.delegate = self

let urlStr : NSString = vehicleImages[imageIndex].stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!




url=NSURL(string: urlStr as String)
imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(url,placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

}
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView

}
```

Comment: I wonder if you might need to include an image to describe the problem? I suspect you'd need to show three sub-images: before, and after (what you get now), and after (what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these methods. May be it will help. I have scroll view stretched to controller's view size. `customizeScrollView()` will calculate min and max scale options. `centerImageView()` will put UIImageView in the center of your UIScrollView

```
fileprivate func customizeScrollView() {
    guard let image = imageView?.image else { return }
    var minZoom = fmin(self.view.frame.width / image.size.width, self.view.frame.height / image.size.height)
    minZoom = fmin(1.0, minZoom)

    scrollView?.contentSize = image.size
    scrollView?.minimumZoomScale = minZoom
    scrollView?.addSubview(self.imageView!)
    scrollView?.setZoomScale(minZoom, animated: false)
    centerImageView()
}

fileprivate func centerImageView() {
    guard let imageView = imageView else { return }
    guard let scrollView = scrollView else { return }

    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var frameToCenter = imageView.frame

    // Center horizontally
    if frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2
    } else {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0
    }

    // Center vertically
    if frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2
    } else {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0
    }

    imageView.frame = frameToCenter
}
```

Also UIScrollViewDelegate methods:

```
/// `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol implementation
extension ImagePreviewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    public func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        centerImageView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, after zooming cant scroll to the end width of image, Height is ok.