# UIScrollView scrolls out of image after image is zoomed in?

Tags: ios, swift, zooming

I'm trying to implement a image zooming functionality using UIScrollview. where as I kept image as aspect fit.
Image is inside a UIScrollView, and image frame has been given similar to UIScrollView.
Here is my code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        scroller.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scroller.maximumZoomScale = 7.0
    }

    // MARK: - User Defined Methods

    @IBAction func doubleTapGestureAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if scroller.zoomScale == 1
        {
            scroller.zoom(to: zoomForScale(scale: scroller.maximumZoomScale, center: sender.location(in: sender.view)), animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            scroller.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
        }
        print(isZoomedIn)
    }

    func zoomForScale(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect
    {
        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        zoomRect.size.height = image.frame.size.height / scale
        zoomRect.size.width  = image.frame.size.width  / scale
        let newCenter = image.convert(center, from: scroller)
        zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
        zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
        return zoomRect
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
    {
        return image
    }
```

Comment: check your image scale

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these methods. May be it will help. I have scroll view stretched to controller's view size. customizeScrollView() will calculate min and max scale options. centerImageView() will put UIImageView in the center of your UIScrollView

Call the `customizeScrollView` function in viewDidload.

```
fileprivate func customizeScrollView() {
    guard let image = imageView?.image else { return }
    var minZoom = fmin(self.view.frame.width / image.size.width, self.view.frame.height / image.size.height)
    minZoom = fmin(1.0, minZoom)

    scrollView?.contentSize = image.size
    scrollView?.minimumZoomScale = minZoom
    scrollView?.addSubview(self.imageView!)
    scrollView?.setZoomScale(minZoom, animated: false)
    centerImageView()
}

fileprivate func centerImageView() {
    guard let imageView = imageView else { return }
    guard let scrollView = scrollView else { return }

    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var frameToCenter = imageView.frame

    // Center horizontally
    if frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2
    } else {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0
    }

    // Center vertically
    if frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2
    } else {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0
    }

    imageView.frame = frameToCenter
}

 public func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        print(imageView.frame)
        centerImageView()
    }
```

Comment: what is your error actually? is that the white space while scrolling?

Comment: My requirement is that the image should be scrolled up to it's content. but it is scrolling out the image space after zoomed in.

Comment: similar to this question?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869355/photo-zoom-setting-aspect-ratio-and-then-zooming-leaves-white-area-swift-code

Comment: Yes i have the same problem

Comment: the same above code works for me. please set the imageview to screen width and around 200 height. and set the imageview content mode to "aspectfill" try the above function. it works

Comment: and also put the imageview to center of the view. There is a little updation, a scrollview delegate method extra. Please check the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var imgDemo: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return img
    }()


    var scrollView:UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
        scroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.25
        scroll.clipsToBounds = true
        return scroll
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imgDemo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        imgDemo.image = UIImage(named: "5.jpg")
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.frame = imgDemo.frame
        scrollView.addSubview(imgDemo)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgDemo
    }

}
```